# TryValidateObject not showing Errors

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, data-annotations

I'm trying to validate data inside a Silverlight 5 application over DataAnnotations. I wrote a couple of custom ValidationAttributes which are working fine as long as I validate inside the Setter of the Properties. If the user opens the Data Form where I'm doing this validation and just presses the "save" button, without making any changes on the properties, I want to validate the whole Object. At this part my implementation is not working as expectet. I wrote a method which uses Validator.TryValidateObject(). In the results I see that the ValidationExceptions are getting thrown, but they are not showing up on the UI. Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong? I guess that the system has no idea on which property the Exception was thrown?

```
public bool ValidateObject()
{
    var validationItems = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var result = new List<ValidationResult>();

    Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), result, true);

    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var error in result)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(error.ErrorMessage = LanguageManager.Instance.GetLanguageString(error.ErrorMessage));
        }
    }

    return result.Count != 0;
}
```

The LanguageManager is an object which returns the error message in the current selected language.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Binding Engine handles Validation Exceptions and will read errors where IDataErrorInfo is implemented, but in both cases, this will only happen when the target property changes.

If you want to raise validation errors outside of the scope of a set operation, you should implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This interface will enable you to build a list of errors in your Click handler. You then raise an ErrorsChanged event for those properties that are invalid, and the Binding engine takes care of the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me. I already had implemented the INotifyDataErrorInfo but forgot to set the ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True on the control binding.

    <Controls3:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Supervisors}" SelectedValue="{Binding SecondSupervisor, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=False}" />

Thanks a lot!